# UIViewController Problem with IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

This is what I do

1. Setup a view with UIViewController Subclass
2. Go to IB, and pull a view into the iphone
3. Pull a navigation bar over the UIView
4. Pull a tableview on the space below.

Everything appears well when I am running the interface builder.

But these things do not work.

1. If I add a button on top of the Navigation Bar, the button appears but IBAction is not called. The button seems to be at a level beneath the Navigation Bar (somewhere else)
2. If I add a footer view for the tableView, it does not appear. I believe the UIView is again masking it or something...

   ```
   - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section                

   {

   UIView *viewForFooter = [[UIView alloc] init ];
   UIButton *footerButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 40, 100, 40)];
   footerButton.titleLabel.text = @"Forgot Login";
   //self.forgotLogin = footerButton;
   [viewForFooter addSubview:footerButton];    
    return viewForFooter;


   }
   ```

WHY ?

Comment: You have to link the button to a selector using IB. have you done that?

Comment: Are you setting the delegate and data source of the table view? Also, do you have a `UINavigationController` set up?

Comment: Please edit your previous post [UIBarButtonItem not reacting to click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445170/uibarbuttonitem-not-reacting-to-click) rather than making new posts for the same problem.

Comment: Everything is done properly. !

Comment: why not just make a UITableViewController?

Comment: @Jordan Brown: Yes. That is how I had done it in my experience. I tried this one today for a particular view, and I still do not know why such a simple thing does not work...

Comment: i think you should just use what you usually do, avoid getting into stuff that you can't get to work. better to just keep it simple, ya know?

Comment: @Legolas let me know if youre able to fix it. if not ill try to look into your problem more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) **No reaction to click**: Try to add the action in code. If it works, something was wrong with connecting up the IBAction.

```
[self.barButton setTarget:self];
[self.barButton setAction:@selector(IBActionHandler:)];
```

As a backup, you can also try to add the button in code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone 
                         target:self
                       selector:@selector(IBActionHandler:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
[barButton release];
```

---

2) **Invisible button** - I think your button is a custom UIButton, so it is transparent. The title is not visible because you have to set it like this:

```
[footerButton setTitle:@"Forgot Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If you want a regular rounded angle button you have to set the frame **after** creating it.

```
UIButton *footerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
// Careful, this button is autoreleased.
[footerButton setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 40, 100, 40)];
```

BTW, something might also be wrong with your CGRects. The footerView should perhaps also be properly initialized with a frame, and you might have to implement

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

as well.

PS: To go with a standard UITableViewController might actually be a good idea.
Happy coding!